# Elapsed Time C Program using struct

Tags: c, time, struct, stopwatch, elapsedtime

```
//import library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//declare variable structure
struct time{
    int hour;
    int min;
    int sec;
}startTime, endTime, different, elapsed;

//mould struct and compute elapsedTime
struct time elapsedTime(struct time start, struct time end){

    int secondStart, secondEnd, secondDif;

    secondEnd = end.hour * 60 * 60 + end.min * 60 + end.sec;
    secondStart = start.hour * 60 * 60 + start.min * 60 + start.sec;
    if (secondEnd>secondStart)
        secondDif = secondEnd - secondStart;
    else
        secondDif = secondStart - secondEnd;

    different.hour = secondDif / 60 / 60;
    different.min = secondDif / 60;

    return different;
}

//main function
void main(){
    printf("Enter start time (Hour Minute Second) using 24 hours system : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", startTime.hour, startTime.min, startTime.sec);

    printf("Enter end time (Hour Minute Second) using 24 hours system : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", endTime.hour, endTime.min, endTime.sec);

    elapsed = elapsedTime(startTime, endTime);
}
```

Can someone help me check and run the code to check whether it is working or not?

Comment: Can you please reformat the code ?

Comment: My friend tried running, execute successfully but failed to run.

Comment: You can view the source code here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/watwdp7b7vmjbb8/elapsed.c?dl=0

Comment: Don't post external links to your code. You should [edit] your post to include the code, select it, and press Ctrl+K

Comment: If you intended these to be time-of-day values entered, then your *else* case is wrong.  To account for time going over midnight, `24 * 60 * 60 + secondEnd - secondStart`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistakes in main function, you should use in scanf `int *` instead of `int` so you must add `&`, you can see below:

```
//main function
void main(){
    printf("Enter start time (Hour Minute Second) using 24 hours system : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &startTime.hour, &startTime.min, &startTime.sec);

    printf("Enter end time (Hour Minute Second) using 24 hours system : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &endTime.hour, &endTime.min, &endTime.sec);

    elapsed = elapsedTime(startTime, endTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would want to calculate `different.sec` so I think the correct calculation of the different time is:

```
secPerHr = 60 * 60;
secPerMin = 60;

if (secondDif >= secPerHr) {
different.hour = secondDif / secPerHr;
secondDif -= different.hour * secPerHr;
}
if (secondDif >= secPerMin) {
different.min = secondDif / secPerMin;
secondDif -= different.min * secPerMin;
}
different.sec = secondDif;
```

Also, for testing purposes you would probably want to display the result in your main function.